# Post of form in table

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a @company known in my view and also @shops which is displayed on a table.

Each row of the table contains a button for the user to click on.

The click on that button should trigger a create in Clients and client belongs to both a Shop and a Company.  The shop_id I want to send with a post request together with the company.

I need to generate a post request per line in the table.  How do I do that?  With a form_for?  And how do I do it per row?  And how do I send the shop_id (of that row) and company_id (in the view) to the post?  I don't want to use params[:shop_id] because the user can change that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.  You need to use a hidden field:

```
<%= form_for '', :url => company_clients_url(shop), :html => {:method => :post} do %>
   <%= hidden_field_tag 'shop_id', shop.id %>
```

Later in the controller you can pick it up with params[:shop_id]

Hope this helps somebody else out.